# Boost Iostreams zlib_error with Custom Source

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, compression, boost-iostreams

I am trying to use a `zlib_decompressor` to decompress data through an `istreambuf_iterator`. I couldn't find an in built way to use an input iterator as input to a stream (please point out a way if one exists already) so I wrote this source:

```
template <class cha_type, class iterator_type>
class IteratorSource {
    public:
        typedef cha_type char_type;
        typedef boost::iostreams::source_tag category;
        iterator_type& i;
        iterator_type eof;

        IteratorSource(iterator_type& it, iterator_type end) : i(it), eof(end) {
        }

        std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n) {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if(i == eof) {
                    std::cout << "Reached eof after " << j << " bytes\n";
                    return -1;
                }
                char next = *i++;
                std::cout << "Reading " << next << "\n";
                *s++ = next;
            }
            return n;
        }
};
```

And used it like this:

```
int main() {       
    std::vector<char> data_back = {'\x78', '\x9c', '\x73', '\x04', '\x00', '\x00', '\x42', '\x00', '\x42'};
    auto start = data_back.begin();
    IteratorSource<char, decltype(data_back)::iterator> data(start, data_back.end());

    boost::iostreams::filtering_istreambuf def;
    def.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    def.push(data);
    boost::iostreams::copy(def, std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

To give this output:

```
Reading x
Reading �
Reading s
Reading 
Reading 
Reading 
Reading B
Reading 
Reading B
Reached eof after 9 bytes
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::iostreams::zlib_error> >'
  what():  zlib error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not sure why this is producing an error because loading from a file works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** In response to the clarified question (in the comments below), here's a trivial adaptation I did of your original sample, that *JustWorks™* on my box:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <class cha_type, class iterator_type>
struct my_source {
    typedef cha_type char_type;
    typedef boost::iostreams::source_tag category;

    iterator_type& it;
    iterator_type end;

    my_source(iterator_type& it, iterator_type end = {}) : it(it), end(end) 
    { }

    std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n) {
        std::streamsize result = 0;
        while ((it!=end) && n--) {
            ++result;
            *s++ = *it++;
        }
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {       
    std::string const rawdata {'x', '\234', '\313', 'H', '\315', '\311', '\311', 'W', '(', '\317', '/', '\312', 'I', '\341', '\002', '\0', '\036', 'r', '\004', 'g' };
    std::istringstream iss(rawdata, std::ios::binary);

    auto start = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(iss);
    my_source<char, decltype(start)> data(start);

    boost::iostreams::filtering_istreambuf def;
    def.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    def.push(data);

    boost::iostreams::copy(def, std::cout);
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c58e2a69b43af802)**

---

#### *Old answer*:

I think you can use just any stream, like stringstream:

```
std::istringstream iss("hello world\n");

filtering_streambuf<input> def;
def.push(zlib_compressor());
def.push(iss);
boost::iostreams::copy(def, std::cout);
```

or to decompress:

```
std::string const rawdata {'x', '\234', '\313', 'H', '\315', '\311', '\311', 'W', '(', '\317', '/', '\312', 'I', '\341', '\002', '\0', '\036', 'r', '\004', 'g' };
std::istringstream iss(rawdata, std::ios::binary);

filtering_streambuf<input> def;
def.push(zlib_decompressor());
def.push(iss);
boost::iostreams::copy(def, std::cout);
```

This works like a charm here. (Sorry for the octal escapes: it's what bash gave me

```
printf "%q\n" "$(echo hello world | zlib-flate -compress)"
```

and I'm lazy enough to keep it that way).

See full example **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05edebd024bd5d54)**

---

**Alternatively** Boost Iostreams accepts a streambuffer, so you can equivalently

```
def.push(*iss.rdbuf());
```

Comment: Sorry that this was not made clear in the question, but my goal is to be able to use an input iterator specifically to provide the bytes to be decompressed.

Comment: @Ell wokay, I've changed my answer. I've coded it up from scratch. No time to look at what you did differently. Hope this helps