# Use boost serialization and zlib together

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, zlib

I have a problem using boost serialization and zlib together. 
When serialize and compress for output I code:

```
boost::asio::streambuf compress_buf;
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream compress_os;
compress_os.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
compress_os.push(compress_buf); 
boost::archive::binary_oarchive compress_oa(compress_os);
compress_oa << model;
```

When de-serialize and de-compress I code:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_istream compress_is;
compress_is.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
compress_is.push(compress_buf);
boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(compress_is);
ia >> model;
```

where model is a class, and the code compile fine.

However,When I de-serialize and de-compress, VS2010 crashed at line

```
ia >> model;
```

In the zlib.hpp, line 388, function

```
template<typename Alloc>
bool zlib_decompressor_impl<Alloc>::filter
```

Message:

Unhandled exception at 0x000007fefd34940d in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > at memory location 0x002fe258..

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You should do these steps (setting up filters) in exactly the reverse order when deserializing as you were using them for serializing the data.

Comment: Perhaps you have the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19551213/85371

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you mean change the setting up order? I tried but it seems not work